# How to check what the user entered after a bot message using discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, discord, discord.py

I recently started to make discord bots. So I have this discord bot with the feature to ask the user a would you rather question. So the bot gets a question from a list of questions and sends a message asking the user to choose the first or second option. Moreover, I want the bot to respond to the user's response saying something like "good choice." However, it is not working and is giving me errors. What is the correct way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
# Event registered when bot recieves a message
@Client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # Don't do anything if the message is from the bot
    if message.author == Client.user:
        return


    if message.content.startswith("$Hi"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello")


    # WOULD YOU RATHER GAME COMMANDS


    if message.content.startswith("$WYRG"):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(ListOfWYRGQuestions) + "\n\n Please enter 1 or 2 for option 1 or option 2.")

        if message.content.startswith("1"):
            await message.channel.send("Good choice!")
        elif message.content.startswith("2"):
            await message.channel.send("Good Choice!")
```

What would be a more precise and correct way to respond to the user's response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you have the `is message.content.startswith("1")` in the scope of `if message.content.startswith("$WYRG"):` This is paradoxical as the message needs to start with both `$WYRG` and `1` or `2` at the same time (as the function gets called from start on each message)

To fix this you should move the `is message.content.startswith("1")` and `is message.content.startswith("2")` out of the scope and maybe use a `game_state` variable so these commands can only be called when the `$WYRG` command is called first. This is the code I wrote:

```
game_state = False
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global game_state

    # Don't do anything if the message is from the bot
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return


    if message.content.startswith("$Hi"):
        await message.channel.send("Hello")


    # WOULD YOU RATHER GAME COMMANDS


    if message.content.startswith("$WYRG"):
        await message.channel.send(random.choice(ListOfWYRGQuestions) + "\n\n Please enter 1 or 2 for option 1 or option 2.")
        game_state = True
    if message.content.startswith("1") and game_state:
        await message.channel.send("Good choice!")
        game_state = False
    elif message.content.startswith("2") and game_state:
        await message.channel.send("Good Choice!")
        game_state = False
```

Hope this makes sense  :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be using $WYRG and $Hi, I recommend you take a look at the [d.py commands framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/index.html), and as for the answer for how to get the next message, look into the [wait_for](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for) client method, it can also be set to time out after x seconds, so it automatically quits the game